# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Tags: asp.net-web-api, tokens

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET WEB Api, y estoy usando la generación del Token, en Internet Explorer me genera la cadena del Token:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero usando cualquier otro navegador me muestra el siguiente error...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código AJAX:

```
function ObtenerToken(user, password) {

            var data = { username: user, password: password, grant_type: "password" }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:50196/Token',
                method: "post",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json",
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Hubo un error al intentar autenticar al usuario.');
                    console.log(e);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var token = response.access_token;
                    alert(token);

                }
            });
        }
```

Al archivo Startup.Auth.cs tengo agregado lo siguiente:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

En WebApiCofig.cs:

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: edita tu pregunta, mejor dicho traduce tu pregunta al idioma de esta comunidad

Comment: José, si encontraste la respuesta, puede responder tu propia pregunta, así puedes ayudar otros usuarios de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Trata removiendo esta parte de **WebApiConfig.cs**:

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Y define en la clase controlador lo siguiente:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class MiClaseController : ApiController
...
```

Comment: EL controlador ya tiene agregado [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]

Comment: Probé lo tuyo, me marca lo siguiente:

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50196/Token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49172' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: ¿Y borraste la primera parte?

Comment: Si, del web.config lo quité....

Comment: En IE si funciona, pero Chrome y Opera noo